# jquery mobile calender not get json data from server

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have this calender plugin, it picks the json file on the cal.js file

```
var calEvents = [
{"icon": "bars","eid":"1","title":"My event test","url":"#","start":new Date("2014-02-10T08:00:00.000Z"),"end":new Date("2014-02-10T10:00:00.000Z"),"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
{"eid":" 1","title":"My event test","url":"#","start":new Date("2014-02-10T17:00:00.000Z"),"end":new Date("2014-02-10T18:00:00.000Z"),"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
{"eid":"someID 1","title":"My event 1","url":"#","start":date1,"end":date1,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
{"icon": "info","eid":"2","title":"Event testing 2","url":"#","start":new Date("2015-04-03 18:54:00.000000"),"end":date3,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
{"eid":"SomeID 3","title":"My event 3","url":"#","start":date4,"end":date4,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
{"icon": "alert","eid":"SomeID 4","title":"My event 4","url":"#","start":date5,"end":date6,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
{"eid":"SomeID 5","title":"Just testing the calendar","url":"http://www.example.com","start":date7,"end":date7,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
{"eid":"SomeID 6","title":"My event 6","url":"#","start":date8,"end":date8,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
{"eid":"SomeID 7","title":"My event 7","url":"#","start":date9,"end":date9,"discription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet sem risus. Curabitur vehicula lacus eu tincidunt interdum."},
];
   $("#calendar").jqmCalendar({
      events : calEvents,
      months : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      days : ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
      startOfWeek : 1
   });
```

I have the json file on generated with php, I am trying make a call to the php json file with this.

```
var calEvents = "http://localhost/indicium/admin/data/app-calender.php";
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

how do I call the php json properly?

Comment: All your code does is assign a string to variable. Research Ajax and [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: am i making the sever json call right ?

Comment: You aren't making a server call. You are simply storing a string (`"http://localhost/.../app-calendar.php"`) in  a variable

Comment: how do i make the sever call ?

Comment: By using Ajax or JQuery's .getJSON method. Read the link I posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to use a concept know as [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).
JQuery has some built in methods for simplifying AJAX.

Here is a very simple JQuery example that retrieves a JSON object from [jsonplaceholder.typicode.com](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) and displays it on screen.

```js
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

$.ajax({
    url: root + '/posts/1',
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
    $('.output').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data) + '</pre>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>The following object is loaded from a remote server...</p> 
<div class="output"></div>
```

Your code could look something like this...

```
var root = 'http://localhost/indicium/admin/data/app-calender.php';

$.ajax({
    url: root,
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
    initCalendar(data);
});

function initCalendar(data) {
  $("#calendar").jqmCalendar({
      events : data,
      months : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      days : ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
      startOfWeek : 1
   });
}
```

---

Documentation:

[JQuery .ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)
[JQuery .getJSON (Short hand for .ajax)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)